# Marrying two of your own characters

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, background, romance

I am a normal RPer and writer who’s in their first D&D campaign. I want to make it so that my next two characters are a married couple who are roaming the lands and picking up jobs as they search for each other after a magic-based accident separated them.

Is marrying two of your own characters weird to those who play the game?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already. Note that Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, where questions are expected to be such that a single "best" answer can be chosen. It's not like a typical discussion [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go), which are less structured. As such, this question will likely be closed due to being primarily opinion-based.

Comment: ...In addition, I don't understand how you would play two separated married characters at the same time if they're not in the same place in the narrative... Let alone the complication of playing 2 characters at once in your first ever D&D game. Are you the DM or a player? (If you're the DM, of course, you're actually "playing" every single character in the narrative, but the players are generally each playing one member of a single party of characters that spend most of their time during the game adventuring together...)

Comment: D&D players and playstyles come in many forms, and "weird" is subjective. This is an opinion-based survey question, and any answers here won't necessarily reflect the opinions of your players.

Comment: @V2Blast I don't think they're proposing to play two characters at once in the same game; I think they intend to play these two characters in different (subsequent?) games/campaigns, there being a linking meta-narrative that the characters are married but somehow magically separated. (The question is still probably not a good fit for the stack, but it's an interesting concept, and seems to me not too dissimilar to the not uncommon practice of playing the relatives or descendants of one's previous characters.)

Comment: @Carcer You could very well be correct, but remember that this *is* the asker's first *D&D* campaign… and, perhaps, first tabletop role-playing experience. (RP can mean different things to different folks!) The asker might be better served by asking a question like *Can I play two characters simultaneously?* (Also, since normally a new PC is introduced after the previous becomes unplayable (usually *via* death), this scenario, in the abstract, sounds terribly tragic!)